# What is this php address bar variable

Tags: php

I am learning about SQL injection following [these walkthrough](http://hacktracking.blogspot.ro/2013/08/redtigers-hackit-wargame-level-3.html). The address bar looks like this:

```
https://redtiger.labs.overthewire.org/level3.php?usr=MDQyMjExMDE0MTgyMTQ
```

The first step is to generate an error by changing the value of this variable:

```
https://redtiger.labs.overthewire.org//hackit/level3.php?usr\[\]=
```

I am not experienced in web programming, but I know how to send form values in address line. However, the page source does not contain `usr` variable. What is this?

Answer (score 1):

The actual URL requested is available in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Querystring parameters will be found in `$_GET` ... in this case, look at `$_GET['usr']`

These values would typically be produced as a result of a form submission. Look for input elements on the page with the `name` attribute of `usr` or multiple elements with the name `usr[]` in the second case. That would allow multiple entries to end up in an array server-side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Are there any aspects I have not yet addressed?